# Use case Diagram

Tags: oop, uml

I am developing an online DVD rental system. This is what I have done so far. Can anyone guide me as to what's lacking in following diagram and how I can improve it?

[image]

The requirements are:

- Users can browse the catalogue of films.
- While browsing the user may add films to their rental list.
- Users can view and modify their rental list (in particular, change priority of the films).
- Registration on the website includes setting up a regular card payment, which is verified by an external payment system.
- DVDs are dispatched using an external mail delivery company.
- Users can report any problems using an online form.
- Company staff can modify user rental lists (e.g., in response to a reported lost disk).

Comment: Please be more specific in your question. That will increase the chance to get a (good) answer.

Comment: This is my image of the use case - It's a link to the use case. I'm new here.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, your UCs are not too bad at all. A few remarks:

- The boundary shall resemble the system under consideration. The UC bubbles are inside, but the actors are outside of it.
- Name UCs with predicate/subject[/object].
- Don't let yourself mislead by implicit orders of UCs ("While browsing"). A UC is always a single added value. When ever people start using include/extend they intend to do functional decomposition, which is wrong. So you should just leave them out and concentrate on the added values. If the order is important constraints can be used instead. This way you will not be trapped by "accidental functional decomposition".

Like always I recommend reading Bittner/Spence on use cases to get a profound understanding of the matter.